# featuring different sub-menu fonts with a simple jquery vertical accordion menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have a simple jquery vertical accordion and would like to have different font sizes, colours and weights for top and sub-menu level links. I'm not having much luck achieving this with changing the CSS. What am i missing? Is there a simple way to do it:

**html code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
          $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
          $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
       }
    });
 });
</script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

and here is my **CSS code:**

```
}
#nav {
float: left;
width: 155px;
border-top: 1px solid #999;
border-right: 1px solid #999;
border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
#nav li a {
display: block;
background: #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 3px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 3px;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
background: #999;
color: #fff;

}
#nav li ul {
display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
}
#nav li ul li a {
background: #ececec;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 3px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 3px;

}
```

Any enlightening on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should target the submenus:

```
ul#nav li ul li {
    /* some css here to change font etc */
}
```

Or to target the 'a' tags within the submenus:

```
ul#nav li ul li a {
    /* some css here to change font etc */
}
```